# What is uncomfortable science (Tukey 1954)?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I came across the term "uncomfortable science" on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomfortable_science) where it is defined:

- Situations where the same data is used for model development (exploratory data analysis) and model testing (confirmatory data analysis).

I found the book where the term was first defined (Tukey, J. 1954: Unsolved Problems of Experimental Statistics, Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 49, No. 268, bottom page 718). Here it says:

> Statisticians must face up to the existence and varying importance of
>   systematic errors. The failure of the statistician to take sufficient
>   cognizance of systematic errors has been in part an escape phenomenon.
>   To a man looking hopefully for a way to shorten a confidence interval
>   by 7 per cent of its length by ingenious devices, the thought of
>   systematic errors which might make it twice as long comes as a severe
>   shock, and all men try to avoid shocks. Perhaps, too, the recent
>   development of statistics in connection with the uncomfortable
>   sciences like agriculture and biology -uncomfortable because
>   unsystematic errors tend to be so large - may have much to do with
>   this. Only the sampling survey statisticians, with their recent
>   treatment of "non-sampling errors" seem to be facing up to the
>   existence of systematic errors.

From this I understand the definition of uncomfortable science being:

- Situations where random error is so large that systematic errors cannot be identified.

However, I have only seen examples of texts using the former definition.

My question is: Are these two definitions the same? And if so, how are they linked?

Comment: I put the large quote in a quote box to emphasize that it is a quote. You are welcome to roll this back or continue editing. You can see the versions in the "edited" quote above.